# Ansible, delete everything except X newest folders

Tags: ansible

Is possible to edit find module command to find X latest folders inside remotebackup dir? Thanks

```
  - find: paths="{{ remotebackupdir }}" age="**find_oldest_folders_except_X_newer**" recurse=no
    register: result

  - debug: var=result.files

  - file: path: "{{ remotebackupdir }}" state: absent
    with_items: result.files
```

Answer (score 3):

Ive done something similar.

Try something like this: (to be executed in the directory where the files are that you want to delete)

```
- name: Get first 4 files
  command: ls -trd -1 {{path}}/* | head -4
  register: filenames

- name: actually delete files
  file: {{path}}/{{ item }} state=absent
  with_items: filenames.stdout_lines
```

Basically -tr lists things in reverse date order, and -1 ensures everything is on one line, and -d says directories only

Comment: Be aware that [parsing `ls` can cause issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) if you don't have "normal" filenames, in which case you might be able to hack something together with `find`, or you can write a custom script in perl/python/ruby.  But if you have good control over the files that will live here, then this will be fine.

Comment: This is grabbing the 4 oldest, not all but the 4 newest. But gives good ideas on how to do it